# Put a space between floated divs and bottom div

Tags: css, html, margin

I'm trying to create a div on the bottom of two floated divs, but with a margin between the bottom div and the others.

Here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QH7q8/10/)

html:

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
    <div class="left">Hello</div>
    <div class="right">Hello</div>
    <div class="bottom">Hello</div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.right {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bottom {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a clear class it works for me ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QH7q8/12/)):

```
<html><head></head>
<body>
    <div class="left">Hello</div>
    <div class="right">Hello</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="bottom">Hello</div>
</body>
</html>​
```

```
.left {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.right {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bottom {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

​

Comment: I always try to get as less divs as possible in order not to have a big messy div hell in my code but thanks ayway, works perfetly :)

Comment: I'm trying to do so too, but in the case of clearing floatings I prefer the extra <div> for clarity/readability.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are clearing those floats (with clear: both), the margin of the final div doesn't position it away from them. In fact, that margin is effectively *hidden* behind the floats.

It's tempting to get around this by introducing an extra element — either an empty clearing element just after the floats, or a wrapper around them.

However, in the interests of keeping markup as clean as possible, it's often appropriate to just add bottom margin to the floats.

So you must define this margin to the first div. So it will work like this:

CSS:

```
.left {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.right {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.bottom {
    clear: both;
}
```